# Adding Meta Boxes to Custom Post Type not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I've tried many things to fix this, I'm fairly new to coding a plugin but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have created a custom post type ("Book") perfectly fine. Now I'm trying to add meta-boxes into it. I can't seem to get the coding to connect to each other properly.

I've tried adding the slugs of each meta box to the "support", I've tried various instances of function and add_meta_box as well as putting different things under  "register_meta_box_cb" and nothing I'm doing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function post_type_book() {


    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'book', 'author_station' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Custom Book Entry', 'author_station' ),
        'supports'              => array('title'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'genres', 'series', 'tags' ),
         'register_meta_box_cb' => ('as_add_book' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
         'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Book'),
        'capability_type'       => 'page',

    );
    register_post_type( 'as_book', $args );

}

function as_add_book( $meta_boxes ) {
    add_meta_box(
        'add_meta_boxes',
        array( $this, 'as_add_book_boxes' ));

     $types = array('post', 'page', 'book');

   if (in_array($types)) {
      add_meta_box(
        'as_add_book',
        'add_meta_boxes',
        'Book',
        'as_add_book_callback',
        $types,
        'normal',
        'high'
      );

   }
    $prefix = 'as_';


    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'as_add_book',
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Book', 'author_station_book' ),
        'pages'=> array('as_book'),
        'context' => 'advanced',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'autosave' => 'false',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'id' => $prefix . 'book_cover',
                'type' => 'image',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Book Cover', 'author_station_book' ),
            ),
            array(
                'id' => $prefix . 'book_title',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Title', 'author_station_book' ),
            ),

    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'as_add_book' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_meta_box' ) );
function my_custom_meta_box(){

  $args = array();

  add_meta_box(
    'my_metabox_id',
    __( 'My Meta Box', 'my_textdomain' ), // Title
    'my_callback_function',               // Callback function that renders the content of the meta box
    'post',                               // Admin page (or post type) to show the meta box on
    'side',                               // Context where the box is shown on the page
    'high',                               // Priority within that context
    $args                                 // Arguments to pass the callback function, if any
  );
}


function my_callback_function( $args ){

  //The markup for your meta box goes here

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.